# How to Check for Shared Accounts

Tags: security, ip-address

We have an application that includes a voting component.

To try and minimise voter fraud we allow N number of votes from the same IP address within a specific period. If this limit is hit we ignore the IP address for a while.

The issue with this approach is if a group of people from a school or similar vote they quickly hit the number. Their voting can also occur very quickly (e.g. a user in the class asks his classmates to vote which causes a large number in a short period).

We can look to set a cookie on the user's computer to help determine if they are sharing accounts or check the user agent string and use that too.

**Apart from tracking by IP, what other strategies do people use to determine if a user is a legitimate or a shared account when the actual IP is shared?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to prevent cheating in on-line voting, the answer is: you can't, unless you use something like SSL client certificates (cumbersome).

Some techniques to make it harder would be using some kind of one time token sent trough  e-mail or SMS. Every smart kid knows how to cheat control cookies using privacy mode of modern web browsers.